# Fresh Virtualmin install - MySQL root password?

Tags: server, mysql, virtualmin

I've searched and searched as this seems like such a newbie problem but after many hours still haven't found the answer.
I followed [this guide](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-and-utilize-virtualmin-on-a-vps).

I did a fresh install of Virtualmin GPL on a fresh Ubuntu 14.04. I can't seem to activate that Webmin module, it keeps telling my that my MySQL root user/pass info is incorrect :

[image: http://i.imgur.com/EkuNhvZ.jpg]

---

[image: http://i.imgur.com/pmteWkv.jpg]

This is my first time doing those things and I really don't know what to do now. Please take a little time to help me, thanks !

Comment: please output of `mysql --version`

Answer (score 1):

You can reset your MySQL instance with

```
sudo dpkg-reconfigure mysql-server-5.5
```

If you are using another version of MySQL change the (5.5) (execute `mysql --version` from command line to find the version).

After doing that use the username and password to connect from Virtualmin to your MySQL.